# Java regular expression not working as expected

Tags: java, regex

I am using java regular expression to split my string into substrings of 2 characters each. I am using the following code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        String str = "admins";
        String delimiters = "([a-z]{2})";

        String[] tokensVal = str.split(delimiters);

        System.out.println("Count of tokens = " + tokensVal.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokensVal));
    }
}
```

But running the following code prints the value of count to zero and prints an empty array.

Comment: You use two letters as the _delimiters_ here. I don't understand why you are surprised by the result?

Comment: yeah i want to delimit by two letters? So what is wrong in that? If I want to delimit by space i use string.split(" "). So if want to split into two characters strings then shouldn't I be using the above mentioned code?

Comment: No you should not, because the delimiters in `.spltit()` are _consumed_. And this is not what you want, it is?

Comment: okay..thanks..I got it..The delimiters are not retained in the actual string. thats why it is showing empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the regex as delimiter will try to split the string by eliminating the characters matched in by the expression. I guess you want these characters itself as a substring so `String.split()` will not help.

Try this:

```
    String str = "admins";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".{2}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(match);
    }
```

Output:

```
ad
mi
ns
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class ApachePOI{
     public static void main(String []args) {
         String str = "admins";
         String delimiters = "(?<=\\G.{2})";

         String[] tokensVal = str.split(delimiters);


         System.out.println("Count of tokens = " + tokensVal.length);
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokensVal));
     }
}
```

output:

```
Count of tokens = 3
[ad, mi, ns]
```

Comment: Perhaps it is good to note that this splits the string up into exact groups of 2 characters, if he'd only want letters (Or only lowercase letters) he'd still have to use [a-z] (or [a-z], [a-zA-Z] or \w) and needs to add an optional amount of characters to the front of the delimiter (for example, like: `\W*(?<=\\G\w{2})`)

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested, Here is a solution without using Regex:

```
String str = "admins";
    String splittedStr = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1;) {
        splittedStr = new String (new char[] {str.charAt(i),str.charAt(i+1)});
        i=i+2;
        System.out.println(splittedStr);
    }
```

output:
ad
mi
ns